# Dual boot win 10 home/ubuntu: Restore windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10, restore

Long story short: Ive been running dual boot win10/ubuntu for a few months now and everything has been mostly fine. Game in windows, do everything else in ubuntu. Recently I discovered that my internet speed in win10 is slow as molasses and I haven't been able to figure out why so I was contemplating a restore for the win10 operating system.

Does this mean I will have to reinstall my ubuntu as well or will the windows 10 restore stick to its own partition and leave ubuntu alone?

I know Ill need to redo my grub, thats fine, I just really don't want to reinstall ubuntu every time windows craps out on me.

Comment: That's kind of hard to determine if it will or won't wipe out your Ubuntu partition, but I have seen system recoveries that want to wipe out all other partitions and return the system to factory defaults.  Might be best to check with the manufacturer of your system and see if their recovery performs removal of partitions and creating new ones.  Regardless, it is always best to have a back up of your system or most importantly, your home folder.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was install Ubuntu on an external drive, and booting Ubuntu every time I needed it. Today I have one machine to each system.

Comment: I can see the sense of that but for me ubuntu is the main system that I boot 90% of the time. I only really use windows for gaming.

Answer (score 0):

What is the meaning of restoring Win Ten? Reset or clean install? What build are you running? Are you over tweaking privacy, removing some or all bloatware, disabling services, telemetry… Slow Internet is a side effect since 18.03.

Comment: I believe I am on win10 1809 though that did install when the problem was already present. Not sure exactly which build I was on before as it has been probably more than a month since I had booted the system to windows. I followed a few guides about slow internet in win 10 and tried a few of the suggestions there but none had any effect. Not sure if I tried all the things you are talking about ofcourse, I'm not much of a win admin truth be told. At the very least back in december it was fine as I remember installing some steam games with good download speeds during my holiday.

Comment: Did you try DNS? Adguard or cloudflare for example to speed up Internet..